# Retrieving hashmap values in XSLT 2.0 Using Saxon-HE

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

I want to pass Map object as parameter in XSLT 2.0 version and i want to retrieve the Map object data under XSLT 2.0 file using Saxon-HE.

I googled a lot and found [Retrieving hashmap values in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434898/retrieving-hashmap-values-in-xslt)

link which completely matches according to my need but i am getting exception such as

> Static error in {map:get($mapData,'1')} in expression in
>   xsl:variable/@select on line 23 column 94 of transformer.xslt:
>         XPST0017: Cannot find a 2-argument function named {http://ns.saxonica.com/map}get().

I don't know where i am doing mistake.

These are the my files.
SexsonDemo.java

```
   public static void transform(String xmlFile, String xslFile) throws TransformerException,
      TransformerConfigurationException {

   TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslFile)));
   Map<String,String> mapData = new HashMap<String,String>();
   mapData.put("1", "188 E 6th Street");
   transformer.setParameter("mapData", mapData);
   transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFile)), new StreamResult(System.out));
  }
```

transformer.xsl

```
xmlns:map="http://ns.saxonica.com/map" exclude-result-prefixes="map" >

<xsl:variable name="mapData"/>
<xsl:variable name="addressData" select="map:get($mapData,'1')"/>
```

at below line i getting exception 
`map:get($mapData,'1')`

[image: transformer.xsl]

Comment: So which version of Saxon HE exactly do you use? And using maps is easier in XSLT 3 as it has its own `map(*)` type and you can use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#makeMap-java.util.Map- and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#XdmMap-java.util.Map- to construct an XSLT/XPath 3 map from a Java Map.

Comment: Hy  Martin Honnen Thanks for reply,I am using Saxon HE-9.8.0-14 version.

Comment: How to read map object in xslt 3.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for reading XDM maps in XSLT, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwZ which has three examples

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="mapData" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" select="map { '1' : '188 E 6th Street' }"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>XPath 3.1 map example</h1>
          <section>
              <h2>function call syntax</h2>
              <p><code>$mapData('1')</code>: <code>{$mapData('1')}</code></p>
          </section>
          <section>
              <h2>map:get</h2>
              <p><code>map:get($mapData, '1')</code>: <code>{map:get($mapData, '1')}</code></p>
          </section>
          <section>
              <h2><code>?</code> operator</h2>
              <p><code>$mapData?('1')</code>: <code>{$mapData?('1')}</code></p>
          </section>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For setting this parameter from your Java code, consider using the Saxon s9api http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html to run Saxon and then you can use hhttp://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#setStylesheetParameters-java.util.Map- to pass in an XdmMap constructed from your Java Map with http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#makeMap-java.util.Map-.

Short Java sample is

```
public static void MapExample() throws SaxonApiException {
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);

    XsltExecutable executable = processor.newXsltCompiler().compile(new StreamSource("sheet.xsl"));

    Xslt30Transformer transformer = executable.load30();

    Map<String,String> mapData = new HashMap<String,String>();
    mapData.put("1", "188 E 6th Street");

    HashMap<QName, XdmValue> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    parameters.put(new QName("mapData"), XdmMap.makeMap(mapData));

    transformer.setStylesheetParameters(parameters);

    transformer.applyTemplates(new StreamSource("input1.xml"), transformer.newSerializer(System.out));

    System.out.println();        
}
```

Comment: The constructor `new XdmMap(java.util.Map)` only works if the `java.util.Map` is a `Map<XdmAtomicValue, XdmValue>`. If you want to pass in a `Map<String, String>` then the static `makeMap()` method is a better option.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
Is there any equivalent for XdmMap.makeMap in standard Java API?
The other part of my problem is that the stylesheet parameters are being sent by other project(s) and they'll have to include a Saxon dependency to use XdmMap.

Comment: If "standard Java API" means the SUN/Oracle JAXP API then the answer is no, it is geared towards XSLT 1.0 which has only support for the XSLT/XPath 1.0 data types (well, it is kind of generic as to what it supports but it was designed towards XSLT/XPath 1.0). In terms of the dependency I am not sure what you are referring to, your original sample uses a Java Map/HashMap and can continue to use that, only the part setting the parameter before running the transformation needs to use the `XdmMap.makeMap`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the namespace URI {http://ns.saxonica.com/map} was used during some early Saxon experiments in implementing maps, long before they were part of the W3C specification: see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.4/extensions/map.html

That specification was long ago superseded by the W3C map functions, which are in namespace http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map.

That's part of your problem. The other part is how to convert a Java map to an XDM map. You can do this in Saxon 9.8/9.9 using the static method `XdmMap.makeMap(java.util.Map)`. It might be easier in some cases to pass in a string containing a JSON representation of the map, and then parse it within the stylesheet using the parse-json() function.

Comment: Thanks for response. given information is more useful to me.